what can I do if log is truncated for Simulation in solana transaction
before submit transaction, I use connection.simulateTransaction to  test, but I got a simulation error. However, when I try to check logs, I found the log was truncated.
Humm. so what can I do if I want to know why transaction simulation failed


This is a tough problem to solve unfortunately. If the logs get filled up, there isn't too much you can do.
The error does say ProgramFailedToComplete, which means that there was a panic or the transaction used up too many compute units. It also gives an index 9, so the 9th instruction caused the issue. Maybe you can reduce your transaction to isolate the problem to that instruction.
Otherwise, you might be able to get a bit information if you send the transaction for real (without simulation) and get the full error logs there.
